# Quser with New-Object (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

My team is currently migrating DHCP to a new Azure server, and when we cutover a particular scope, we manually check if any users are logged in to desktops within the leased IPs before restarting them.

I pieced together 2 scrips to help automate the checking of logged in users. The first successfully retrieves the hostnames for the leased IPs in a particular scope, then exports them to txt.

The second queries the hosts from the results in script 1 using the `quser` command within a custom object, and that is what I am having troubles with. I thought I'd use `New-object` to retrieve the users but the results don't look right or seem to be missing data compared to running the `quser` command manually for each of the servers in question.

Essentially, I am looking for a better way to retrieve logged on users, with the results showing server name, and if a user is logged on, what the user name is (same info as running quser command).

```
Function Get-File($initialDirectory) {   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$scopeservers = Get-File
$servers = Get-Content $scopeservers

foreach ($server in $servers) {$properties = @{
                                               Server = $server
                                               LoggedInUsers = quser /server:$server
                                              } 

                               $o = New-Object psobject -Property $properties; $o
                               }
```

Alternatively, I tried using `Get-CimInstance` or `Get-WmiObject`, but all I got were "RPC SErver Unavailable" errors with those commands.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem` has the hostname, and username of the person logged in. Just have to pass it a/multiple computer(s) using `-ComputerName`.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get logged on users using `Invoke-Command` to run a Scritpblock on the remote machine.

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {$env:COMPUTERNAME; quser}
                               write-host " "}
```